# How can I have multiple dropdown lists (with different options) next to each other in the reponse?

Tags: qualtrics

I want to be able to have users input time - (I am asking when users do a certain activity during the day)

I want to have 2 dropdown lists next to each other in the response:

- one with choices 1, 1:30, 2, 2:30,..., 12:30 and
- the other dropdown to show AM/PM.

How can I do this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about UX, not a coding problem (better-suited for http://ux.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Im not sure it is off topic - It is a question about HOW to have 2 dropdown lists with different options next to each other. I dont know how to do this. Sorry I phrased this question this way - it may have been better if I just asked how to do the above.

Comment: Ah, ok.  In that case, please update the title (etc.) to reflect the "How do I do X?".

Comment: thank you. would you perchance know how I can do this in qualtrics??

Answer (score 3):

Use a Side by Side question type with two columns.